# ¿Como ejecutar un recyclerview desde un field de firestore como filtro?

Tags: android, firebase, recyclerview, sql, studio

Tengo una base de datos en Firestore con una colleccion "Padron", la cual va a contener una gran cantidad de documentos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la imagen, estos documentos de la coleccion "padron" tiene un field "CLUB".
De la misma forma los documentos de la collecion "Usuarios", cuentan con el mismo fieldo "CLUB".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo 2 categorias de usuarios, "Admin" y "Client" que ejecutan sus respectivas activitys teniendo en cuenta el "CLUB".

```
private void loginActivity() {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    usersRef.document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    String type = document.getString("CLUB");
                    if(type.equals ("ASV")) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, UserAdmin.class));
                    } else if (type != ("ASV")) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, UserClient.class));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Mi problema con todo esto es que cuando un usuario "Client" (Solo debe visualizar el recyclerview) ingresa a ver el "Padron", el recyclerview deberia mostrar solo los documentos con el mismo valor "CLUB" que tiene el usuario solicitante y no encuentro como hacer eso.

Adapter:

```
public class JugadoresMasc_Adapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<JugadoresMasc, JugadoresMasc_Adapter.ListaHolder> {

public JugadoresMasc_Adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<JugadoresMasc> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListaHolder holder, int position, @NonNull JugadoresMasc model) {
    holder.tv_apellido_player.setText(model.getAPELLIDO());
    holder.tv_nombre_player.setText(model.getNOMBRE());
    holder.tv_dni_player.setText(model.getDNI());
    holder.tv_club_player.setText(model.getCLUB());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListaHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_jugadores,
            parent, false);
    return new ListaHolder(v);
}

class ListaHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_apellido_player, tv_nombre_player, tv_dni_player, tv_club_player;

    public ListaHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_apellido_player = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_apellido_player);
        tv_nombre_player = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre_player);
        tv_dni_player = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dni_player);
        tv_club_player = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_club_player);
    }
}

public void deleteItem(int position) {
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
}
```

}

Lista:

```
public class JugadoresMasc {

private String APELLIDO;
private String NOMBRE;
private String DNI;
private String CLUB;
private String SEXO;

public JugadoresMasc(){

}

public JugadoresMasc(String APELLIDO, String NOMBRE, String SEXO, String DNI, String CLUB){
    this.APELLIDO = APELLIDO;
    this.NOMBRE = NOMBRE;
    this.DNI = DNI;
    this.CLUB = CLUB;
    this.SEXO = SEXO;
}

public String getAPELLIDO() {
    return APELLIDO;
}

public String getNOMBRE() {
    return NOMBRE;
}

public String getDNI() {
    return DNI;
}

public String getCLUB() {
    return CLUB;
}

public String getSEXO() {
    return SEXO;
}
```

}

Funcion del Recyclerview:

```
private void PadronMasculinoClient() {
    Query query = jugadoresRef.orderBy("APELLIDO", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<JugadoresMasc> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<JugadoresMasc>()
            .setQuery(query, JugadoresMasc.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new JugadoresMasc_Adapter(options);


    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_masculino_client);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Todo esto funciona bien, el problema es que nose y no encuentro como hacer ese "Autofiltro" para que el Recycler solo me muestre documentos con de un valor especifico que sea igual al del usuario que lo consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para traer usuarios con el filtro que querés usar para llenar ese RecyclerView, deberias usar las queries compuestas que ofrece Firebase, podes ordenar por apellido y por club, por ejemplo, esta Query te traeria de esa colección todos los usuarios cuyo apellido sea el que vos le pasas y club sea el que vos le pasas.

```
Query query = jugadoresRef.whereEqualTo("APELLIDO",apellido).whereEqualTo("CLUB",club)
```

Solo cambiando esto, ahora los documentos que vas a traer de esa colección van a venir filtrados por apellido y club de acuerdo a los parametros que vos le mandes en esa clausula.

Tené en cuenta que cuando uses esto vas a necesitar crear una query compuesta en Firestore, por lo que cuando ejecutes por primera vez este código, tu recyclerview no va a mostrar nada, para eso anda al logcat, y fijate que Firebase te indica que necesitas crear la query compuesta siguiendo un link, clicka ese link y ya se genera esta query en la consola, despues que se genere, solamente ingresa de nuevo a la app y ya deberia tu recyclerview solo mostrarte docmentos que cumplen esta condicion dentro de tu recyclerview

Podés leer mas sobre esto en la documentación
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=es

O seguír uno de mis videos que explico como crear estas queries

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKTfnF6hVV0

Comment: Excelente tu comentario, lo habia pensado por ese lado, pero no sabia que tenia que hacer un query compuesto. Otra consulta, obviamente el valor del field "CLUB" numca es el mismo, ya que es segun cada usuario client, deberia convertirlo en string o pomerlo??

Comment: Si, vos pasas a esta query lo que queres filtrar, por ejemplo por String deberias pasar el apellido que queres filtrar con el club que querés, si te sirvió la respuesta podes marcarla como correcta, un saludo

Comment: Si si, mañana lo pruebo, hoy dia a full con mis hijos, jajaja

Comment: Para capturar el valor del club tenés que hacer una query antes para obtener los clubes y después esta